# Church numerals in lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

I need to find a function P such that (using Beta - reduction)

```
P(g, h, i) ->* (h, i, i+1).
```

I am allowed to use the successor function succ. From wikipedia I got

```
succ = λn.λf.λx.f(n f x)
```

My answer is `P = λx.λy.λz.yz(λz.λf.λu.f(z f u))z`

but I'm not quite sure about it. My logic was the `λx` would effectively get rid of the `g` term, then the `λy`.`λz` would bring in the `h` and `i` via the `yz`. Then the `succ` function would bring in `i+1` last. I just don't know if my function actually replicates this.

Any help given is appreciated

Comment: Is `(h, i, i+1)` a tuple? How are you representing tuples in LC?

Comment: @melpomen yes it is a triple of Church numeral

Answer (score 0):

@melpomene points out that this question is unanswerable without a specific implementation in mind (e.g. for tuples). I am going to *presume* that your tuple is implemented as:

```
T = λabcf.f a b c
```

Or, if you prefer the non-shorthand:

```
T = (λa.(λb.(λc.(λf.f a b c))))
```

That is, a function which closes over `a`, `b`, and `c`, and waits for a function `f` to pass those variables.

If that is the implementation in mind, and assuming normal Church numerals, then the function you spec:

```
P(g, h, i) ->* (h, i, i+1)
```

Needs to:

1. take in a triple (with `a`, `b`, and `c` already applied)
2. construct a new triple, with

   - the second value of the old triple
   - the third value of the old triple
   - the `succ` of the third value of the old triple

Here is such a function `P`:

```
P = λt.t (λghi.T h i (succ i))
```

Or again, if you prefer non-shorthand:

```
P = (λt.t(λg.(λh.(λi.T h i (succ i)))))
```

This can be partially cleaned up with some helper functions:

```
SND = λt.t (λabc.b)
TRD = λt.t (λabc.c)
```

In which case we can write `P` as:

```
P = λt.T (SND t) (TRD t) (succ (TRD t))
```